# How can I install a faucet bidet if my faucet doesn't have a removable aerator?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I really want to install [Aquaus Handheld Bidet for Faucet](https://www.rinseworks.com/products/index.php?route=product/product&path=60_61_65&product_id=53) in my bathroom, but I have one of those faucets that have inner temper-free aerators. It is not like ordinary screwing type aerators. I have attached a picture that resembles what I have. Is there anything that I can do about this apart from replacing my faucet, such as some kind of converter?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If there are no usable threads on the end of your faucet spout, then, short of rigging something up with a piece of rubber hose and some hose clamps, you can't use that style of handheld bidet.

Instead, perhaps consider this type: https://rinseworks.com/product/abt-360-the-aquaus-360-handheld-bidet-for-toilet-nsf-certified-3-year-warranty

It connects to your toilet's water supply, rather than your faucet. Not only is this a more doable solution in your situation, but it will allow you to continue normal use of your faucet.